# Laravel API multiple level

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api

I followed this tutorial: [toptal](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial)

and I would like to create an API for soundbox apps of the type:

```
/ api / v1 / Apps -> list of apps
/ api / v1 / Apps / 1 /category -> list of category of app 1
/ api / v1 / Apps / 1/category/1/sounds -> list of components of category 1 of app 1
```

do you have a tutorial to do this?
or how to adapt my route file? do I have 3 controllers?

-------------- Edit ------------

I created the model and controller :

```
class App extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['title'];
}

class Category extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Controllers :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\App;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AppController extends Controller{

public function index(){
    return App::all();
}

public function show($id){
    return App::find($id);
}
}

<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Category;
use App\App;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller{

public function index(App $app){
    return App::find($app);
}

public function show(App $app, Category $category){
    //
}
}
```

I created migration file:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAppsTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('apps', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}

<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration{
public function up(){
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('app_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('categories', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('app_id')->references('id')->on('apps');
    });
}
}
```

And my routes/api.php file :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
Route::resource('App', 'AppController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
Route::resource('app.category', 'CategoryController', ['only' =>['index', 'show']]);
});
```

so I call the url : /api/v1/App

result : [{"id":1,"title":"Movies","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":2,"title":"football","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]

but I do not understand how this works when I call the url: /api/v1/App/2/category

in the CategoryController.

Comment: Maybe it will be more intuitive to use the following structure of your routes: `/api/v1/categories` -> list of categories, `/api/v1/categories/1/products` - list of products of category 1, `/api/v1/categories/1/products/1/components` -> list of components of product 1 of category 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel's nested resource routes for this, and yes I would have one resourceful controller per entity type. Specify the `--parent` flag when generating your controllers so that the respective models will be injected into your controller methods.

```
php artisan make:controller --resource --model Category CategoryController
php artisan make:controller --resource --parent Category --model App AppController
```

Edit: If you're not setting up authentication, then you probably only want to expose your `index` and `show` methods.

Demo repository: https://github.com/MyTeamName/appstore4233593

## routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
    Route::resource('categories.apps', 'AppController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
});
```

> ```
> +----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
> | Method   | URI                                     | Name                  | Action                                        | Middleware |
> +----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
> | GET|HEAD | api/v1/categories                       | categories.index      | App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index | api        |
> | GET|HEAD | api/v1/categories/{category}            | categories.show       | App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@show  | api        |
> | GET|HEAD | api/v1/categories/{category}/apps       | categories.apps.index | App\Http\Controllers\AppController@index      | api        |
> | GET|HEAD | api/v1/categories/{category}/apps/{app} | categories.apps.show  | App\Http\Controllers\AppController@show       | api        |
> +----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
> ```

## models

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function apps()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App::class);
    }
}

class App extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

## migrations

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('name')->unique();
});

Schema::create('apps', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('title');

    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('categories');
});
```

## controllers

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Category::all();
    }
    public function show(Category $category)
    {
        return $category;
    }
}

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Category $category)
    {
        return $category->apps()->get();
    }
    public function show(Category $category, App $app)
    {
        return $app;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to use 'middleware' => 'auth: api',
if I do not want to set up authentication?

Comment: @kingramizy If you're not setting up authentication, then you probably only want to expose your index and  show methods.

Comment: @kingramizy I have updated my answer for you providing a complete demo repository.

Comment: thanks for your help, i just put my code on git: https://github.com/kingramizy/soundAPI
in fact it's app is the parent of category.
and it does not work for: / api / v1 / apps / 2 / categories /

Comment: Why would a category belong to an app? I think an app should belong to a category. No?

Comment: I have apps, each has categories and each category has sounds. so I have three levels, app / categories / sounds